# Make http put request in nodejs with promise

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

**I need to make a put request to an external api in alexa skill and i didnt find how to do it, help me and you will have luck for 3 minutes**

I need to send a put request with a body using https in node.js

````
const http = require("https");


const getRequest = function(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const client = url.startsWith("https") ? require("https") : require("http");
    const request = client.get(url, response => {
      if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode >+ 300) {
        reject(new Error("Failed with status code: " + response.statusCode));
      }
      const body = [];
      response.on("data", chunk => body.push(chunk));
      response.on("end", () => resolve(body.join("")));
    });
    request.on("error", err => reject(err));
  });
};```
````

Comment: What error or problem are you encountering? It looks like you are defining http as a variable but not using it. If you want to force https, you may want to remove the `const client`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)? just return resolve or reject depends on the api-result

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    request({
        uri: <apiURL>,
        method: 'PUT',
        body: <DATA>,
        json: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
    }, (error, response, body) => {
         if(error){
            return reject(error);
         }
         return resolve(body);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm curious to know, did you get the 3 minutes of luck that was promised in the question?

Answer (score 0):

In this example let's call PUT request to popular [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/) API using NodeJs https.request

1. Prepare a function to make a PUT call and return results as promise
2. To fetch results you can use then() method or you use async/await syntax

   ```
   const https = require("node:https");

   function update(host, path, id, obj) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            host,
            path: `${path}/${id}`,
            port: 443,
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            },
        };
        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            if (res.statusCode != 200) {
                return reject(new Error(`HTTP status code ${res.statusCode}`))
            }

            const body = [];
            res.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk))
            res.on('end', () => {
                resolve(Buffer.concat(body).toString())
            })
        });
        req.on('error', (e) => {
            reject(e.message);
        });
        req.write(JSON.stringify(obj))
        req.end();
    });
   }

   async function asyncCall() {
      const result = await update(
                 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', 
                 '/posts', 
                 10, 
                 {
                     id: 10,
                     title: 'Sample Title',
                     body: 'Sample Body',
                     userId: '1'
                  });
       console.log(result);
   }
   asyncCall();
   ```